# Azure Data Factory truncating files in a copy pipeline from an S3 bucket to ADLS

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, amazon-data-pipeline

I have a copy pipeline set up to copy a handful of files from a daily folder in an S3 bucket into a data lake in Azure using data factory. I run into this really weird issue.

Suppose there are three files in the S3 bucket. One is 30MB, another is 50MB, and the last is 70MB. If I put the 30M file 'first' (name it test0.tsv), then it claims it successfully copies all three files to ADLS. But, the second and third file are truncated to 30M. The data is correct for each file, but, it is truncated. If I put the 70M file first, then they are all copied properly. So, it is using the first file length as max file size and truncating all subsequent longer files. This is also very worrisome to me since the Azure Data Factory claims it successfully copied them.

Here is my pipeline:

```
{
"name": "[redacted]Pipeline",
"properties": {
    "description": "[redacted]",
    "activities": [
        {
            "type": "Copy",
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "FileSystemSource",
                    "recursive": true
                },
                "sink": {
                    "type": "AzureDataLakeStoreSink",
                    "copyBehavior": "PreserveHierarchy",
                    "writeBatchSize": 0,
                    "writeBatchTimeout": "00:00:00"
                }
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "InputDataset"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "OutputDataset"
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "retry": 3
            },
            "scheduler": {
                "frequency": "Day",
                "interval": 1
            },
            "name": "[redacted]"
        }
    ],
    "start": "2018-07-06T04:00:00Z",
    "end": "2018-07-30T04:00:00Z",
    "isPaused": false,
    "hubName": "[redacted]",
    "pipelineMode": "Scheduled"
}
```

}

Here is my input dataset:

```
{
"name": "InputDataset",
"properties": {
    "published": false,
    "type": "AmazonS3",
    "linkedServiceName": "[redacted]",
    "typeProperties": {
        "bucketName": "[redacted",
        "key": "$$Text.Format('{0:yyyy}/{0:MM}/{0:dd}/', SliceStart)"
    },
    "availability": {
        "frequency": "Day",
        "interval": 1
    },
    "external": true,
    "policy": {}
}
```

}

Here is my output dataset:

```
{
"name": "OutputDataset",
"properties": {
    "published": false,
    "type": "AzureDataLakeStore",
    "linkedServiceName": "[redacted]",
    "typeProperties": {
        "folderPath": "[redacted]/{Year}/{Month}/{Day}",
        "partitionedBy": [
            {
                "name": "Year",
                "value": {
                    "type": "DateTime",
                    "date": "SliceStart",
                    "format": "yyyy"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Month",
                "value": {
                    "type": "DateTime",
                    "date": "SliceStart",
                    "format": "MM"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Day",
                "value": {
                    "type": "DateTime",
                    "date": "SliceStart",
                    "format": "dd"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "availability": {
        "frequency": "Day",
        "interval": 1
    }
}
```

}

I have removed the format fields in both the input and output dataset because I thought maybe having it be a binary copy would fix it, but that didn't work.

Comment: I should mention I am using V1 Azure Data Factory

Comment: Looks like a bug.  You should consider raising a support ticket with Microsoft or upgrade to ADFv2 and see if the issue reoccurs, (bearing in mind the upgrade path is *probably* what MS will tell you to do in the event you raise a ticket).